# MPDF Images rendering with yellow color

Tags: php, image, pdf, rendering, mpdf

I'm rendering Some images on a PDF and the images are losing their original colors, showing with yellow colors. I need this images to be rendered with original colors.
[image: Image rendered on PDF]

I already set $mdf->img_dpi to a hight value but this not resolved the problem. I also realized that this just happen with images that were downloaded from remote server via http with copy() PHP function.

I need this images to be rendered wit original colors.Does anyone had this same problem and found a solution?

Original Image Link
https://zapangelo.zapcorp.com.br/fit-in/620x372/smart/filters:quality(90):format(webp)/3163263/7f892766-4176-4981-924b-e08277f200f5_raw.jpg

Comment: The link responses with an image in "webp" format and not JPEG. You should provide a link to the real original file.

Comment: That's is the real original file link, I just tried to convert the image from webp to jpg but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved downloading the jpeg version of the image (original image was webp ).